# setting the environment variable error

Tags: command-line-interface

I am trying to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directly i am currently working on.

This is the command which i gave.

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

In response, i received the following error.

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH: Undefined variable.
```

The main purpose of the command is to set the library path as the current working directory since i am not granted a super admin power to copy my files in the usr/lib folder.

How to solve this

Comment: Oh bleeping bleep. Are you using [(t)csh](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)?

Comment: yes... @Ignacio

Answer (score 1):

It means that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set in your env. Try

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .
```

Comment: Thank you. But now it says, export command not found :(

Comment: I didn't say `export`. I said `setenv` :)

Comment: ^^ yeah i gave `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then executed the command. Now it says `export command not found`

Comment: you don't need to run any export command. Just `setenv` is enough.